# Can I apply the transform to a path so the transform itself is no longer needed?

Tags: svg.js

Is it possible to "apply" a transform to a node using SVG.js? I'm not asking about how to add a transform attribute to a node, but recalculate that node's coordinates so the transform itself is no longer needed - it is now baked into the coordinates of the node itself. For example, let's say I have a polygon (really, a rectangle) of (0,0) (100,0) (100, 10) (0, 10) and I have a scale transform applied to it of 2x. I'd like to flatten this node so it does not have the transform anymore, but is now (0,0) (200,0) (200, 20) (0, 20)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. If you have a path and  you use the arc command in your path, not all transformations can be applied 1to1 so that the path looks the same.

If you are OK with this limitation, you can loop through all commands of the path array and apply the transform to every point individually.

Untested pseudocode:

```js
const pathArray = path.array()

for (const cmd in pathArray) {
  // this will not work for h, v and z commands 
  const x = cmd.pop()
  const y = cmd.pop()
  const p = new SVG.Point(x,y).transform(path.transform())
  cmd.push(p.x, p.y)
}

path.untransform().plot(pathArray)
```

For polygons, you can do the same but with the points array instead.
Rectangles can be converted to polygons first

Comment: Sorry - totally forgot to comment. This indeed works! Thank you so much for your prompt response.

Comment: @NikI. You can click on the checkmark next to the answer to accept it as correct. That helps other people to see if the question has a valid answer and rewards me with some points :D